# Remove UIView from UIScrollView in XAMARIN

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, xamarin, subviews

i have several controls (subclasses of UIView) placed on a UIScrollView. Now I want to remove them from the UISrollView and create new controls. The code below runs but has no effect!
What am i doing wrong?

```
        for (int i = 0; i < myScroll.Subviews.Length; i++) {
            Console.WriteLine (myScroll.Subviews [i].GetType ());
            myScroll.Subviews [i].Dispose ();
            myScroll.Subviews [i] = null;
        }
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use RemoveFromSuperview():

```
foreach(View sub in myScroll.Subviews)
{
   sub.RemoveFromSuperview();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must remove your control/view only from **super** view:
If you have those hierarchy of controls

```
CustomControl <- UIView <- UIScrollView
```

You can find *CustomControl* (with help of method `ViewWithTag(int tag)`) inside of parents *UIView* or *UIScrollView*.
**BUT**: to remove *CustomControl*successfully, you must call only:

```
UIView.ViewWithTag(tag).RemoveFromSuperView();
```

and next line of code will not remove your control:

```
UIScrollView.ViewWithTag(tag).RemoveFromSuperVew();
```